# Android Basic Push Notification Send from client side doesn't work

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I'm looking for some help with push notifications on Android.

Situation:

I'm trying to do a push send from an Android device, at this time for itself ( will understand later) but when I hit the send button nothing happens

Config:

- Firstly, yes, the client side push is enabled.
- Secondly my onCreate method in the "extends Application" class

  ```
  public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  //Parse
  //Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
  Parse.initialize(this, "", "");
  ParseObject.registerSubclass(Groups.class);
  ParseObject.registerSubclass(Users.class);

  //Subscribe to push
  ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
  @Override
  public void done(ParseException e) {
      if (e == null) {
          Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
      } else {
          Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
       }
   }
  });

   // Save the current Installation to Parse.
   ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
   }
  ```
- My button to send the push notification ( its the basic code from the docs )

  ```
       sendReqBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {

          System.out.println("Debug push onclick");
          ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
          push.setChannel("");
          push.setMessage("The Giants just scored! It's now 2-2 against the Mets.");
          push.sendInBackground(new SendCallback() {
              @Override
              public void done(ParseException e) {
                  System.out.println("Push send done");
              }
          });
      }
  });
  ```
- All other settings set by the basic android tutorial (Like manifest and basic sdk adding, I already use other parse functions)

So after this code snippets added to my app I hoped that I will get a notification on the device itself as described earlier, but nothing happens. From the parse push dashboard I tried it, and it works fine (thats why I think the manifest and other things are configured well) and in the core panel on the dashboard i can see the installation in the list and the "" mark in the channels array.

Can anyone help me out? 
Thanks in advance!! 
Steve

Comment: u resolved  your issue ?

Comment: As I know in the latest release of the sdk its resolved but since I use an other way that was needed in my app ( send the pushes for specified users queried by installation ) . If you need more help leave one more comment and I will share my whole code to you as an answer !

Comment: actually i have pointer(User)  in installation table so i m not getting idea how to save that pointer (User) in installation table  i have saved user information in  User table succesfully kindly share your code to save pointer(user) in installation table and then to send notifications (might be an array of user)  using their object id (already saved in Installation table )